# get more verbose output from grub and solve "error: you need to load the kernel first"

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows and when selecting Ubuntu at grub boot menu I get several `error: Command failed.` and finally `error: you need to load the kernel first.` prompted. When selecting Windows I get a few `error: Command failed.`. If I instead press escape, issue `exit` to the CLI and then select Ubuntu or Windows, it works. The issue isn't completely consistent either. Sometimes it just works and sometimes i get thrown directly to grub command line instead. The issue arised after a BIOS update (and several windows updates) which i believe might have changed some kind of settings. I tried running Boot Repair with no luck. [Pastebin from Boot Repair](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4g3JFHmkj7/).

What might cause these kind of issues and how can I get some more verbose output from grub? I have tried to edit `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash debug --verbose"`, but the error occurs before that output.

Comment: Start by disabling Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's already disabled.